# Implicit super constructor is undefined with Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, java-6

I have the following base class and sub class:

```
public class BaseClass<T> {
    public BaseClass(T value){
}

public class NewClass<T> extends BaseClass<T> {
    public NewClass(T value){
    }
}
```

I get the following error: Implicit super constructor BaseClass() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your subclass cosntructor to:

```
public class NewClass<T> extends BaseClass<T> {
    public NewClass(T value){
        super(value);
    }
}
```

If you don't add `super(value);`, then compiler will automatically add a `super();`, which will chain to a `0-arg` constructor of super class.  Basically, your original subclass constructor is compiled to:

```
public NewClass(T value){
    super();
}
```

Now you can see that, it tries to call `0-arg` super class constructor, which the compiler cannot find. Why? Since in super class, you have provided a `1-arg` constructor, compiler won't add any default constructor there. And hence that error.

You can also avoid this problem by giving an explicit `0-arg` constructor in your super class, in which case, your original sub class code will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

if it asks to explicitly invoke another constructor, just do it:

```
public class NewClass<T> extends BaseClass<T> {
    public NewClass(T value){
        super(value);
    }
}
```